# Замена не экспортируемой функции C++

Tags: c++

Дано: Главный main.exe файл, вызывающий библиотеку libs.dll. В этой библиотеке есть не экспортируемая функция, которую я хочу заменить на свою.
Как заменить я знаю, но мне нужен адрес входа в функцию. 
Вопрос: Как можно получить этот самый адрес(например, для экспортируемой функции можно пользоваться функцией GetProcAddress, в моем случае это не сработает).

P.S. Два дня пытался ковырять адреса в ollydbg, но все без толку ...

Comment: Вам где менять? В памяти? На диске в файле? По размеру-то новый код на место старого влезет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать такую схему:

1. Вызываем GetProcAddress для экспортируемой функции (какой - неважно. Какая-нибудь в dll всяко есть. Главное - попасть в диапазон адресов dll), получаем указатель на экспортируемую функцию.
2. Прибавляем к этому указателю некое смещение, которое есть разница адресов между искомой функцией и экспортируемой в адресном пространстве dll.

Понятно, что для выполнения пункта 2 нужно знать это самое смещение. Как я понимаю, dll-ка собрана без отладочной информации. Следовательно, название искомой функции в dll нигде не фигурирует. Тогда есть такие идеи:

- Может быть (и скорее всего), эта функция в конце концов вызывается через какую-нибудь из экспортируемых функций. И вы знаете в какой примерно момент это делается. Тогда можно в основной программе вызвать такую экспортируемую функцию, и ходить отладчиком в окне CPU (где ассемблерный код показывается) и входить во все call'ы, пока не попадете в нужную функцию. Тогда смотрим адрес первой команды, и смещение считается тривиально. Даже если нужную функцию таким образом обнаружить сложно, число возможных кандидатов снижается.
- Может быть, вам известен точный фрагмент кода этой функции. Тогда можно поискать соответствующую последовательность байт в диапазоне адресов dll-ки.
- Последний вариант - вам известно лишь примерно, что эта функция делает.
  Тогда остается искать все команды ret в окне дизассемблера в диапазоне адресов dll, вверх от них пытаться найти начало функции (что может быть затруднительно из-за всяких переходов), затем отбросить те, которые экспортированы (и, следовательно, известно, что это не то), затем отбросить те, которые не похожи по выполняемым действиям. А для оставшихся кандидатов - пробовать перебором вставлять ваш код и смотреть, работает или нет.

Comment: Для получения адреса DLL лучше подойдет GetModuleHandle

Comment: Да, но суть от этого не меняется. Все равно надо знать смещение.

Comment: Не смещение, а RVA... В памяти смещение от начала образа как равно RVA. В файле чуть сложнее

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, не буду с вами спорить о терминологии, RVA так RVA. Хотя вы сами пишете, что "в памяти смещение от начала образа как равно RVA". То есть RVA (как и любой адрес) - это частный случай смещения. Собственно, я просто использовал более общий термин.